# Pandas: Setting slice of multiindexed dataframe with values of a series (aligned)

Tags: python, pandas, slice, series, multi-index

I'm trying to set the slice of a data frame that has a multi-index with the values of a series that matches the index values. But instead the whole slice is just filled with NaN.

Consider the following dataframe and series:

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.Index(['a', 'b', 'c'])
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([index, index])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(9)}, index=multi_index)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)  # just to be sure
ser = pd.Series([11, 22, 33], index)
df, ser

     A
a a  0
  b  1
  c  2
b a  3
  b  4
  c  5
c a  6
  b  7
  c  8

a    11
b    22
c    33
dtype: int64
```

Now I'm trying to set the slice with the contents of the series, but the result is unexpected:

```
df.loc[('b',), 'A'] = ser
df

       A
a a  0.0
  b  1.0
  c  2.0
b a  NaN
  b  NaN
  c  NaN
c a  6.0
  b  7.0
  c  8.0
```

And that although the indices agree:

```
df.loc[('b',), 'A'].index == ser.index

array([ True,  True,  True])
```

This should be so simple. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your index only aligns at level 1 not the overall multi index: `ser = pd.Series([11, 22, 33], pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'c')]))` would align correctly. Or you can use BENY's suggestion to break the alignment with `values`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already suspected something like that was the problem. Now I have the choice between this and BENY's suggestion. In any case, I have to make sure of the alignment.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add `values` at the end , to remove the impact of `index` matching for pandas assign

```
df.loc[('b',), 'A'] = ser.values
df
Out[29]: 
      A
a a   0
  b   1
  c   2
b a  11
  b  22
  c  33
c a   6
  b   7
  c   8
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking of that as well, but I'll have to doublecheck that in my case the values are aligned correctly, then it should work.